# Is Dojo Open Source?

Tags: dojo

Can I use Dojo in an business application free of cost?

Comment: Are you going to ask this for jQuery and Prototype too?

Comment: Can you read the dojo toolkit web site?

Comment: You should go to the Dojo website and lookup the license there; the answer is easy to find. Questions like this don't belong here.

Comment: +1 to undo at least one of the down votes. This is not an off-topic or unwelcome question on SO.

Comment: +1 out of protest for all the elitist punks that make SO that much less helpful because they consider certain questions as being beneath them. Some people are just learning and don't know

Comment: If the question had been “How can I tell whether a library can be used in a business application” with Dojo mentioned as an example in the question, then this would have been great — answers would have been full of hints about how newcomers who might not be familiar with licensing can track down answers. But the weakness of the question as it stands is its specificity: we learn only about Dojo.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal information about a product.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> You may:
>
> ```
> * Freely use Dojo to build applications and services
> * Distribute Dojo as a part of commercial products
> * Modify Dojo, make extensions to the toolkit, and produce your own
> ```
>
> add-on components with no requirement
>   that you give your code away or
>   contribute it back to the project
>
> Just to re-iterate, you can build
>   commercial software with Dojo without
>   obtaining a separate license or
>   incurring any other obligations.
>
> Dojo is availble under either the
>   terms of the modified BSD license or
>   the Academic Free License version 2.1.
>   Both licenses grant you broad rights
>   to use and build on and with Dojo in
>   both Open Source and commercial
>   settings.

http://dojotoolkit.org/license

Comment: +1 for providing a comprehensive answer with a link to the license agreement.

Answer (score 6):

According to http://dojotoolkit.org/license

> You may:
>
> Freely use Dojo to build applications
>   and services
>
> Distribute Dojo as a part
>   of commercial products
>
> Modify Dojo,
>   make extensions to the toolkit, and
>   produce your own add-on components
>   with no requirement that you give your
>   code away or contribute it back to the
>   project
>
> Just to re-iterate, you can
>   build commercial software with Dojo
>   without obtaining a separate license
>   or incurring any other obligations.

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course. It is licensed under BSD and Academic Free License.
Both licenses grant you broad rights to use and build on and with Dojo in both Open Source and commercial settings.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see http://dojotoolkit.org/license :

> You may:
>
> ```
> * Freely use Dojo to build applications and services
> * Distribute Dojo as a part of commercial products
> * Modify Dojo, make extensions to the toolkit, and produce your own
> ```
>
> add-on components with no requirement
>   that you give your code away or
>   contribute it back to the project
>
> Just to re-iterate, you can build
>   commercial software with Dojo without
>   obtaining a separate license or
>   incurring any other obligations.